# Alternate Method for Azure Disaster Recovery

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine, disaster-recovery

Currently for our Azure Disaster recovery plan we replicate workloads from a primary site/region to a secondary site. Where we mirror the source VM config and create required or associated resource groups, storage accounts, virtual networks, etc.

We are looking into an alternate method the wouldn't require a second resource group. This would require:

1. Use one, already existing resource group; i.e. `testGroup-rg` in East-US
2. Deploy new IaC components into the same RG but in Central-US

So in the singular resource group, if we wanted a function app, we would have two sets of components. `testFuncApp` in East-US and `testFuncApp` in Central-US.

This way we would only ever have one set of IaC created. Of course we would need to automate how to flow traffic etc. into a particular region if both exist.

Is this a possibility? If it is, is it even necessary/worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to use the same RG.  We need to have a resource group in target region if not Site Recovery creates a new resource group in the target region, with an "asr" suffix.